# SharePoint 2013 Search Center - Alternative for $includeLanguageScript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, display-template, resource-files

Is there an alternative approach to loading the language resource files with `$includeLanguageScript` in SharePoint 2013 Search Center?

Sometimes it happens that the file is not loaded fast enough, resulting in the following error when trying to access the value from the resource file in a display template:

[image]